# How reading exif metadata from file

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, exif, mxml

I'm trying to implement the following Exif reading [library](https://github.com/bashi/exif-as3) with as3, but I can't load the browsed file.

In the library example they use `loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.example.com/sample.jpg"));` for loading the image, the problem in my application is that the file is selected by a file-browser in a local computer.

I tried a fileReference.name but it doesn't work, the only way that I found to make my test, is putting a file in the same directory than the .swf like this :

```
loader.load(new URLRequest("IMG_001.JPG"));
```

Can you tell me what is the parameter that I can put in the `URLRequest` function to get the path of the selected file ?

Thank you

Comment: Please search before posting questions. There are plenty relevant examples how to **load** a file in **AS3** after **browse** dialog.

Comment: @Organis I found only normal loading but not with URLRequest, can you give me an example please ?

Comment: You are not allowed to get the complete file url/path from **FileReference** for security reasons: something that runs in browser gets your local drive structure = not good at all. Still, it's not like you get a different result loading files via **URLRequest**. Make a test app with AIR Desktop target and use the **File** class that extends **FileReference** and also has **File.url** property: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#url

Comment: Is this solved? Use `fileReference`to fill a byte array then simply do a `my_exif = new ExifInfo( myBytesArray);`... This logic is based on the `function onComplete` of [**exifLoader.as**](https://github.com/bashi/exif-as3/blob/master/src/jp/shichiseki/exif/ExifLoader.as). So to use fileRefence bytes, skip using their own exif loader (which also fills a bytes array anyways) and just pass your own user-file bytes to the `ExifInfo` class.